# How can I focus my Kijiji RSS feed question?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

To clarify my question has *not been officially asked*. I just know it has issues that need to be fixed before it is asked officially.

I have a question that is really a collection of several. That needs to be reduced to one or two good ones around a problem I am having with RSS feeds (Unless I created myself an X/Y problem).

I have subscribed to [Kijiji](https://kijiji.ca) custom RSS feed to let me know when new board games are listed. I have [feedly](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devhd.feedly&hl=en) on my android phone and subscribed to the feed. However the frequency it updates is not satisfactory and I cannot change it. The site also has Daily email alerts as a service but that is even worse as far as getting notified timely.

It appears to be driven by the feeds popularity and updates more often depending no how popular it is. I don't have anything authoritative for that, just what I was reading in comments on related posts. Ideally I want something that would be at most 10 minutes behind i.e. If someone posts a listing I am interested in I want to know about it at most 10 minutes after it happens.

I actually build a scraper for Kijiji which seems to work but I have no means to display that data on my phone. I could host it somewhere and even make my own RSS feed on GoogleApps but I'm back to my first problem.

Sending myself emails seems antiquated.

I am new to these concepts so I don't know what my real question is

- Do I want a better RSS reader that I can update more frequently? In that case I am looking for a better Android-reader. Or do feeds not like to work like this and it is an unrealistic request.
- Am I going to roll my own solution for viewing this data? I need some sort of data displaying app for Android I suppose

I trying to find a question that basically is a continuation of: How can I get a centralized location to store new Kijiji listings that is keep updated every ten minutes.

Or even simpler.... How can I get near immediate notification of new Kijiji listings and what software solutions would help with that?

Comment: So the site offers a feed that updates timely? If yes, a feed reader that allows to set the update interval would suffice, correct? I never saw a feed reader that doesn’t offer this feature, though, so unless you have more requirements, the question might be too broad (as you probably could use almost any feed reader for this purpose).

Comment: _I never saw a feed reader that doesn’t offer this feature_. Well feedly doesnt seem to do it. Then I read RSS speed is mostly based on feed popularity which is maybe where I went wrong. Most readers, it seems, I cannot get it down to the <10 minute window I am looking for. I ended up running a PowerShell scraper on my home computer that post to Slack every 10 minutes with new listings.

Comment: If you found out that several feed readers don’t allow to set it to the seconds/minutes you need,  I think a question asking for such a feed reader would be perfectly fine.